# Convert a cell of numbers formatted as numbers to text

Tags: excel, format, excel-2010

Im working on a pricelist where I have partnumbers like '124846' and i am using a Index/Match to get stockvalues from our sql db.

The issue is that the 124846 is saved as a number in the excel files i get. and in the sql connection they are text, so Excel will not match them.

If i select all partnumbers and edit the format to TEXT nothing happens until i double click each cell and hit enter, at which point it converts the number to text.

Anyway to do this automatically without the doubleclick/enter on each cell (3000rows)

/Christian

Comment: Have you tried using the TEXT() function in your INDEX/MATCH formula, e.g. =TEXT(A1,"0")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to convert and run this small macro:

```
Sub NumberToText()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.NumberFormat = "@"
        r.Value = r.Value
    Next r
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**